# Azure PS query to obtain resource providers registered specific to a given resource group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-resource-group

```
Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | Select-Object ProviderNamespace, RegistrationState
```

The above PS query can get me all the resource providers and registered state.

Now, when I have resource-group with a few resources added

Is it possible to script a PS/Cloud Shell query to get the resource providers needed for just the resources in that specific resource group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below, the `$arrayList` is all the resource providers of the resource group.

```
$a = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName joywebapp).ResourceType 
$arrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach($item in $a){
    if($arrayList.Contains(($item -split("/"))[0]) -eq $false){
        $arrayList.Add((($item -split("/"))[0])) | Out-Null
    }  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

just do a `Get-AzResource` and find all the resource types in that resource group, something like:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName xxx | Select-Object ResourceType
```

if you want unique types just use the below :

```
 Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName xxx | Select-Object Resource Type -Unique
```